# How to strip a macOS app to remove debug information?

Tags: macos

`strip`is a unix command to remove all the debug information from an executable, or other information that is not needed for execution. Is there a way to "strip" a macos app to make it smaller and make reverse engineering more difficult? I tried viewing package contents, and striping /macOS/MyGame executable, but then it claimed that it messed it up, and then refused to launch. How do I strip it without "invalidating the code signature" I already asked and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose?

If you plan to distribute the app then using XCode's archiving options is the way to go.

strip command works in MACOS.

Here is a useful script:
https://gist.github.com/neonichu/1662881